# Creating a nav bar from scratch, but having issues with floating links to the right and the alignment

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a homemade nav bar for a website and want my name to appear to the far left and have the links float to the far right. I used CSS to format everything under Nav, but when I use float for the links, it is out of alignment and they appear backwards from how I typed the html for them.

I know I have a major problem with how I'm using CSS, but looking for some insight or maybe a better practice.

I'm avoiding bootstrap or anything predefined so I can get some practice and hardcode it from the ground up.

```css
nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
  background-color: #F7F9F9;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div>Rick Wilson</div>
      <a href="#">Experience</a>
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
      <a href="#">Technology Stack</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: `<div>Rick Wilson</div>` Divs are block level elements by default, so they take up the full width of their container. This pushes the links down.

Comment: Thank you that corrected. Does using the float:right for the links still make sense in this scenario?

Comment: You can use the css grid

Comment: Sure, there's nothing wrong with it. You might also want to look into flexbox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout

Answer (score 1):

You could use the new way of aligning: `grid`.
AND
Let me explain, with `grid` you can align two div so that you do not have to depend on `align`o `float`.

To achieve this you have to generate two divs: one for the logo and one for the links.

Then you declare at the beginning: `display: grid` to use this property and in turn the logo div is positioned as first ( `grid-column: 1 / 2`) and in the links as the second (`grid- column: 2 / 2`).

**One of the advantages of using a grid is that it is partly responsive**.

More info

- [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)
- [Complete-guide-grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
    .navbar {
        display: inline-grid;
        grid-template: 20% 30%;
        background-color: #F7F9F9;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;            
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .logo {
        grid-column: 1/2;
        background-color: #F7F9F9;
    }
    .links {
        grid-column: 2/2;
    }
    .links a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">Rick Wilson</div>
      <div class="links">
        <a href="#">Experience</a>
        <a href="#">Projects</a>
        <a href="#">Technology Stack</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, flexbox is a nice way to handle things like this. In this case, you can wrap your links in another `div` and then use `justify-content: space-between`. For example:

```css
nav {
  background-color: #F7F9F9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div>Rick Wilson</div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">Experience</a>
        <a href="#">Projects</a>
        <a href="#">Technology Stack</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

div tags are going to be block elements unless specified otherwise. For a nav bar, you could use something like an h1 tag. Adding "display: inline" to the h1 tag will align everything to look in a line.

Another tip: to add spacing between your links ("a" tags), you can add padding-left. See below (padding-left: 10px;)

```css
nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
  background-color: #F7F9F9;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar h1{
  display: inline;
}

.navbar a {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <h1>Rick Wilson</h1>
      <a href="#">Experience</a>
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
      <a href="#">Technology Stack</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You HTML is a little off in terms of semantics. I'd do something like:

```
<header>
   <h1>Rick Wilson</h1>
  <nav>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Technology Stack</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS Grid would be ideal for this, but if you can't because of browser requirements, Flexbox would be the way to go:

```
header {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
   background-color: #F7F9F9;

   ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      display: flex;
   }

   li {
      margin-left: 1.5em;
   }

   a {
      text-decoration: none;
   } 
}
```

https://codepen.io/md/pen/LqQeLE